# Errors in DB2 8.0 db2diag.log

Tags: db2, db2-luw

We have a very old PeopleSoft HR system running on DB2 8.x.  Numerous times a day we get the following errors in the db2diag.log file.

```
 2019-11-04-01.22.24.012784-300 E16054C794         LEVEL: Error (OS)
 PID     : 229596               TID  : 772         PROC : db2hmon 0
 INSTANCE: hrprod               NODE : 000
 FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloPdbConnectSocket, probe:20 
 MESSAGE : ZRC=0x810F0019=-2129723367=SQLO_CONN_REFUSED "Connection refused"
 CALLED  : OS, -, connect
 OSERR   : ECONNREFUSED (79) "Connection refused"
 DATA #1 : String, 32 bytes
 Unable to connect socket on path
 DATA #2 : socket, 4 bytes
 7
 DATA #3 : sockaddr, 39 bytes
 0x303B4F38 : 0001 2F75 7372 2F75 7365 7273 2F64 6232    ../usr/users/db2
 0x303B4F48 : 6173 2F64 6173 2F74 6D70 2F64 6173 6E61    as/das/tmp/dasna
 0x303B4F58 : 6D65 6470 6970 65                          medpipe
 DATA #4 : File name, 37 bytes
 /usr/users/db2as/das/tmp/dasnamedpipe
```

We're not sure what's causing the error but the reference to DAS in the error has me thinking the instance is trying to connect to the DAS server, or maybe the other way around.  The DBA who was responsible for the system said the error has appeared for a long time and he couldn't figure out the cause but it had no noticeable negative implications on functionality.  He retired last week.  I'd like to fix the issue if possible.   I'm not familiar with 8.4 and it's use of DAS other than DAS being needed to administer multiple instances, using a GUI, on the same server (there's only one instance on the server).

Any help tracking this down greatly appreciated. :)

Richard

Answer (score 1):

Check the following if it's applicable to your case:
[ECONNREFUSED (79) "Connection refused" message in the db2diag.log for the db2hmon process.](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/econnrefused-79-connection-refused-message-db2diaglog-db2hmon-process)

> **Cause**
>
> The DB2 Health Monitor periodically wakes up and checks for a
>   connection to the DB2 administration server (DAS).
>
> **Resolving The Problem**
>
> This type of error is reported when the DAS (DB2 administration
>   server) is not active. When the health monitor wakes up it checks for
>   a connection to the DAS. In this case the connection is refused as
>   either the DAS does not exist or it is not started.

Comment: Thank you both.  I will try starting the DAS.  I did have some questions on DAS.  Does it need to be running if we aren't using DB2 Control Panel to manage the instance?   If it doesn't, what can be done to stop the health monitor from trying to connect to it (some config option)?  Thanks again, and I'll report back after starting it.

Comment: Just looking at the db2admin options.  Would it just be a matter of "db2admin drop" to have the health monitor not try the connection?  I'm guessing that the "db2admin create" command is what tells the health monitor to start checking up on the DAS.  I'm presuming a "db2admin drop" would stop that from happening.

Comment: It’s clear stated in the message I provided, that dropping DAS doesn’t prevent db2hmon from trying to connect it (check the last phrase cited). Refer the following link to stop db2hmon, if you don’t need to run it and any fenced routines. [How to stop the db2hmon process in DB2 Version 8.2](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-stop-db2hmon-process-db2-version-82).

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I had missed that last line in your original post. :-(

Comment: I'm happy to report that the message hasn't shown up in the log since I started the DAS.  I also turned on DAS auto-start as suggested.  Thanks for the help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In case DAS is not running, which could be the reason Health Monitor cannot connect to it, you can start it by following [these instructions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.gui.doc/doc/t0005170.html):

- Log in as the DAS user (could be `dasuser` or something similar).
- Source the profile to set up command environment:

  ```
  source $HOME/das/dasprofile
  ```
- Run `db2admin start`

To see other options for the command you can run `db2admin -?`.

You can also ensure that DAS starts automatically upon the server startup by running `dasauto -on`.